# ActiveRecord - Group by attribute of included table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following two models

post_comment.rb

```
class PostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

reply.rb

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post_comments
  belongs_to :reply
  ...
end
```

I have the following query that gets all the post_comments and includes their respective replies:

PostComment.all.includes(:replies)

I want to, however, also group the replies of by the reply_id attribute of the reply model

Ideally I'd like to end up with something like the following straight out of the DB:

```
[
  <Post 1:
    replies: { nil: [...], 1: [...], 2: [...], ... }
    ...
  >,
  <Post 2:
    replies: { nil: [...], 123: [...], 341: [...], ... }
    ...
  >,
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ActiveRecord can do that

We can group relies like this,but maybe it isn't the way you want

```
posts = PostComment.all.includes(:replies)
for post in posts
  ...
 replies_map = post.replies.group_by(&:reply_id)
  ...
end
```

you can add a virtual column to model

Answer (score 0):

To group the replies by the `reply_id` attribute of the reply model, you can do this:

```
PostComment.joins(:replies).group('replies.reply_id')
```

Comment: Getting following output:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "replies"

Comment: @delisdeli please try again my updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: I dont think this will return the format I am looking for